# ARM Linux kernel debugging on AT91SAM9261

Tags: linux, kernel, debug, arm, debugger

I have ported Linux to AT91SAM9261 board, I have compiled my own Bootstrap, Uboot, Kernel and filesystem.

Now I want to debug my Linux kernel 2.6.30 using KGDB and GDB. I have host with Ubuntu installed and target (AT91SAM9261) with kernel 2.6.30, I want to debug my Linux kernel 2.6.30  using serial/Ethernet. In KGDB official site they have given KGDB patch for x86, but not for ARM.

**Is it possible to debug my ARM linux kernel on AT91SAM9261?**

Comment: superuser.com is not just for collecting links. Good answer should answer the question, and not just point to another site. Of course, answer may include description and link to source (or "more detailed information and downloads here").